# Why my controller returns array of empty '{}'?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm using .NET core 5. I don't know why I am getting this kind of result from my controllers:

```
[
  {},
  {},
  {},
  {},
  {},
  {},
  {},
  {}
]
```

Here's my controller code:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> SalesPerson()
{
    var salesPersons = await GetAllSalesPersonsByWcf();
    List<SalesPersonDto> salesPersonResult = salesPersons.Select(
    x => new SalesPersonDto()
    {
        Id = x.Code,
        Name = x.Name,
        PhoneNo = x.Phone_No,
        Type = x.SalesPerson_Type == 0 ? "visitor" : "disturbiutor"
     }).ToList();
     return Ok(salesPersonResult);
}
```

in debug mode, I have the value
[image]
But I don't know why I am getting that result.

Also, I have used and that solve the problem

```
Content(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(salesPersonResult), "application/json");
```

My question is why it's happening? and what did I do wrong?

Comment: What type are you specifying as part of your request? Are you adding an Accept header and requesting something other than 'application/json'?

Comment: post your model, are those properties or fields? (must be properties); how are you inspecting result did you just paste what browser/postman printed or did you inspect in from js code already after deserialization in that case paste your frontend model as well?

Comment: @Rafal They are fields

Comment: Continue stepping through the code.  Everything looks good except the empty array.  It just looks like the empty array is linked to the wrong results.

Comment: @ValaKhosravi that is why you do not have values make them properties